Is there a product of a graph and two isolated vertices always bipartite?
Definition 1. A lexicographic product $G \circ H$ of two graphs $G$ and $H$ is a graph such that the vertex set of $G \circ H$ is the Cartesian product $V(G) \times V(H)$ and two vertices $\left(g_1, h_1\right)$ and $\left(g_2, h_2\right)$ are adjacent in $G \circ H$ if and only if

$g_1$ is adjacent to $g_2$ in $G$ or
$g_1=g_2$ and $h_1$ is adjacent to $h_2$ in $H$.

An interesting thing, recently someone reminded me of this:

For a graph $G$, $G\circ 2K_1$ is bipartite where $2K_1$ is the two isolated vertices.

Clearly it is false for general graph $G$. For a counterexample, in the following case $K_3\circ 2K_1$. The $K_3\circ 2K_1$ contains many copies of $K_3$, which is not bipartite.

So an interesting question is, if there are another graph products  $\phi$ that makes the $G \phi 2K_1$ always bipartite.
Or does  $G$  have some special condition for the lexicographic product ?

tensor product?

It's not clear to me what the question is, you want products that have the property of $G\times 2K_1$ being always bipartite? And why do you claim that is true for $\times = \circ$ and then show a counterexample?

According to the given definition, isn't $G\circ2K_1$ simply two copies of $G$ that aren't connected to each other?

@
Greg Martin NO Recall that the lexicographic product $G\circ H $means
substituting (a copy of) $H$ for each vertex of $G$ and
a complete bipartite graph for copies $H_u$ and $H_v $if $G$ has an edge $ (u,v)$.

@Bruno Andrades I edit the question again.

@Karl Yes. The tensor product is a desired product.
